# ASP.net how to parse JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing

I am trying to get a webpage to return itunes search results. while looking through some results here to similar questions i put this code together however i get the error: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary directed at line 41:

```
string trackName = obj2["trackname"].ToString();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project4
{
public partial class project4a : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string choice="";
        if (TextBox1.Equals("Music"))
        {
            choice = "musicTrack";
        }else if (TextBox1.Equals("Movie"))
        {
            choice = "movie";
        }else if (TextBox1.Equals("Software"))
        {
            choice = "software";
        }
        string url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + TextBox1.Text.ToString() + "&entity="+choice ; //+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            //parse
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(json);
            Dictionary<string, object> obj2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            obj2 = (Dictionary<string, object>)(result);

            string trackName = obj2["trackname"].ToString();




            Label3.Text = trackName;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the API for an itunes search is here [https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/]

Comment: did you debug the code? if yes, then share the json data you have received from itunes api

Comment: I've been working with JSON viewer using the web address [https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yellow&entity=musicTrack]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the json returned from the API call looks like the following:

{
 resultCount:number,
 results:array
}

The dictionary will therefore have 2 values in it, one for the key "resultCount" and one for the key "results".

What you want to do is deserialise the results array and then query that:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Simon\Downloads\1.txt"));
Dictionary<string, object> obj2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
obj2 = (Dictionary<string, object>)(result);

object[] resultsList = (object[])obj2["results"];

foreach (var r in resultsList)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> obj3 = (Dictionary<string, object>) r;
    string trackName = obj3["trackName"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: tried it and got this exception returned: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object][]'.'

Comment: @dbart sorry, that was my mistake - I've updated the answer.

Comment: It is not necessary to "construct" obj2 by calling `new Dictionary`.  Instead, declare obj2 when you set it equal to the result like this:
`Dictionary<string, object> obj2 = (Dictionary<string, object>)(result);`

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesnt solve your problem, but a practice for avoiding exceptions.

```
if (obj2.ContainsKey("trackname”))
{
 string trackName = obj2["trackname"].ToString();
 Label3.Text = trackName;
}
else
{
 // Whatever
}
```